# Average of 3 fields in same document

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents stored in my database with exactly the same 'schema'. Each document has three float values (keys are 'A', 'B' and 'C') and what I need to do is output each document projected as the average of all three.

I also need to divide by 100, so my calculation is (A + B + C)/3/100. As far as I understand, I need to project each document as a different output, but $group is no use here (since I'm not averaging across all documents, just each one).

I need to first be able to write this as a MongoDB command, then afterwards translate it to PHP. I think I'll be able to do the PHP part but what I need is a bit of help getting started on the actual MongoDB command...

```
db.measurements.aggregate(   )
```

My data is stored as follows:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId(xxx), "A": 22.34, "B": 23.32, "C": 75.32, "device_id": 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId(xxx), "A": 22.34, "B": 23.32, "C": 75.32, "device_id": 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId(xxx), "A": 22.34, "B": 23.32, "C": 75.32, "device_id": 3 }
```

When I submit a get request, I need my data to come out as follows:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId(xxx), "Average of A,B,C": 40.50, "device_id": 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId(xxx), "Average of A,B,C": 40.50, "device_id": 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId(xxx), "Average of A,B,C": 40.50, "device_id": 3 }
```

After some further research, it seems aggregate is not the method I should be using here? Would it be better if I calculated the average in my php model prior to insertion into my database, and just retrieve my documents via the find() method?

Comment: Please show sample document with the expected output.

Comment: Added to the original post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you essentially need is a single **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** piped aggregation - it will calculate the average for you using the **[arithmetic operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#arithmetic-operators)** available and will modify the result within the same pipeline to get the field as an expression of the calculation `((A + B + C)/3)/100` (if you want a percentage then you need to multiply instead of dividing i.e. calculation is `((A + B + C)/3)*100`). Summarily explained by the following operation:

```
db.measurements.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {               
            "device_id": 1,
            "Average of A,B,C": {
                "$divide": { // ( A + B + C )/3 )/100
                    {
                        "$divide": [ // (A + B + C )/3
                            { "$add": [ "$A", "$B", "$C" ] }, // A + B + C
                            3
                        ]
                    },
                    100
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

That being said, it's best to do heavy or complex computational tasks in the application layer and let mongo best do its data persistence tasks.

Comment: Thanks chridam. Its probably best I do those average calcs in the application layer and store them as additional fields prior to adding to the db.

Comment: @ggwc No worries. Not too sure though if that was a typo in your question; were you meant to multiply by 100 to get a percentage as implied by your expected output or the calculation is correct as is with the 100 divisor?

Comment: yep, its not a %. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Starting from MongoDB 3.2, we can use the [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) accumulator operator with the square brackets `[]` to directly create new array fields in the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage to do this efficiently.

Of course we also need the [`$divide`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/) arithmetic aggregation operator to divide the value by `100`.

```
db.measurements.aggregate(
    [ 
        { "$project": { 
            "result": { 
                "$divide": [
                    { "$avg": [ "$a", "$b", "$c" ] }, 
                    100 
                ] 
            } 
        }} 
    ]
)
```

Translation in PHP gives:

```
db.measurements.aggregate(
    array(
        array("$project" => array( 
            "result" => array( 
                "$divide" => array(
                    "$avg" => array("$a", "$b", "$c"), 
                    100 
                )
            )
        ))
    )
)
```

Comment: Nice one on the 3.2 solution though!